# Rear wheel keeps ending up squint, axel on cassette side lateral movement?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, maintenance, repair

I have an old(?) 2010 Carrera Vulcan MTB and the rear derailleur hanger broke a few months ago (my son accidentally bashed it with his bike). Even though the bike is old, it has not really seen much use until recently.

I replaced the hanger, but in the process dismantled the rear wheel/cassette to give things a check and clean up before replacing (axel looks straight, bearings seems ok). After I put everything back together, the rear wheel keeps ending up squint - to the point where it looks like it's bent the QR skewer. The wheel looks normal shape and the frame and bike itself have not sustained any crash or damage.

It appears that on the cassette side, the axel can move a few mm laterally. When I put the wheel in the dropouts (vertical) it can sit centred, but when I put the chain on the cassette the tension pulls it out of alignment.

I've attached some images to try to illustrate what it looks like - the only thing I can think of is that maybe there is not enough of the axel sticking out the cassette side, but I'm a complete bike repair noob so really not sure what is causing this. I can push it into a centred position and tighten the QR, but after riding it seems to slip out of alignment eventually.

Any other reasons why this might be happening?

[image: Cassette Side Axel in Dropout]
[image: Cassette Side Axel]
[image: Squint Wheel]
[image: Opposite axel side]

Comment: Are you saying that the axle tends to move sideways -- disappearing through the nut on one side and screwing through the nut more on the other side?  If so then likely the bearings are binding.

Comment: What is "squint" in this context ?   I would say there's not enough axle poking into the hanger and dropouts - I'd prefer a little more because frames can flex that much under load.   So there's something going on with the bearings and how they're all stacked up.

Comment: Criggie - Squint means the axel won't move at all on the side opposite the cassette as it fits snugly into the dropout. In the cassette side it looks like there is 1-2mm where it can move left or right. It's the whole wheel that's moving, cassette doesn't wobble or move.

Comment: Daniel - no sorry I wasn't clear in my description: the axel itself it not moving independently of the rest of the wheel, the whole wheel is able to move. From what I can see it's because the derailleur side of where the axel fits into the dropouts has 1-2mm (at most) space which lets the axel sit in a position that renders the whole wheel uncentred. What do you mean by bearings are binding, I'm not familiar with the jargon. Cheers

Comment: The axle is not properly centered relative to the hub.  Presumably this happened when you reassembled the hub.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. Do you mean laterally (side to side) it is not centred and in that case I need to reassemble it but with more of the axel sticking out the derailleur side?

Comment: When it's properly assembled you the axle should stick about equally (withing a mm or two) on both sides.  But looking at the pictures the axle almost seems too short.  I wonder if you somehow reassembled it incorrectly and hence this situation.

Comment: This axle looks far too short. Did you replace it and you were given an axle for a road-bike?

Comment: In the second image it looks like the wheel is too far over to one side, if the wheel isn’t centred within the frame it will look like the axle is short on one end

Comment: It's definitely all the same parts it came with originally. The bolt on the opposite derailleur side is extremely tough to shift however, as the bolt on the derailleur side moves a lot easier so will always be the one to move first if I'm using two wrenches. I'll try to expose some more axel on the derailleur side and see if that helps.